# Python: where is random.random() seeded?

Tags: python, random, cryptography, random-seed

Say I have some python code:

```
import random
r=random.random()
```

Where is the value of r seeded from in general?
And what if my OS has no random, then where is it seeded?
Why isn't this recommended for cryptography?  Is there some way to know what the random number is?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341112/whats-more-random-hashlib-or-urandom) you have simmilar question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Follow *da code*.

To see where the `random` module "lives" in your system, you can just do in a terminal:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/random.pyc'
```

That gives you the path to the `.pyc` ("compiled") file, which is usually located side by side to the original `.py` where readable code can be found.

Let's see what's going on in `/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py`:

You'll notice that it creates an instance of the `Random` class and then (at the bottom of the file) "promotes" that instance's methods to module functions. Neat trick. When the `random` module is imported anywhere, a new instance of that `Random` class is created, its values are then initialized and the methods are re-assigned as functions of the module, making it quite random on a per-import (erm... or *per-python-interpreter-instance*) basis.

```
_inst = Random()
seed = _inst.seed
random = _inst.random
uniform = _inst.uniform
triangular = _inst.triangular
randint = _inst.randint
```

The only thing that this `Random` class does in its `__init__` method is seeding it:

```
class Random(_random.Random):
    ...
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.seed(x)    
...
_inst = Random()
seed = _inst.seed
```

So... what happens if `x` is `None` (no seed has been specified)? Well, let's check that `self.seed` method:

```
def seed(self, a=None):
    """Initialize internal state from hashable object.

    None or no argument seeds from current time or from an operating
    system specific randomness source if available.

    If a is not None or an int or long, hash(a) is used instead.
    """

    if a is None:
        try:
            a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(16)), 16)
        except NotImplementedError:
            import time
            a = long(time.time() * 256) # use fractional seconds

    super(Random, self).seed(a)
    self.gauss_next = None
```

The comments already tell what's going on... This method tries to use the default random generator provided by the OS, and if there's none, then it'll use the current time as the seed value.

But, wait... What the heck is that `_urandom(16)` thingy then?

Well, the answer lies at the beginning of this `random.py` file:

```
from os import urandom as _urandom
from binascii import hexlify as _hexlify
```

Tadaaa... The seed is a 16 bytes number that came from [os.urandom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom)

Let's say we're in a civilized OS, such as Linux (with a *real* random number generator). The seed used by the `random` module is the same as doing:

```
>>> long(binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16)), 16)
46313715670266209791161509840588935391L
```

The reason of why specifying a seed value is considered *not so great* is that the `random` functions are not really "random"... They're just a very weird sequence of numbers. But that sequence will be the same given the same seed. You can try this yourself:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> random.randint(0,100)
13
>>> random.randint(0,100)
85
>>> random.randint(0,100)
77
```

No matter when or how or even *where* you run that code (as long as the algorithm used to generate the random numbers remains the same), if your seed is `1`, you will always get the integers `13`, `85`, `77`... which kind of defeats the purpose (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) about Pseudorandom number generation) On the other hand, there are [use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20636902/289011) where this can actually be a desirable feature, though.

That's why is considered "better" relying on the operative system random number generator. Those are usually calculated based on hardware interruptions, which are very, very random (it includes [interruptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt#Typical_uses) for hard drive reading, keystrokes typed by the human user, moving a mouse around...) In Linux, that O.S. generator is [/dev/random](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random). Or, being a tad picky, `/dev/urandom` (that's what Python's `os.urandom` actually uses internally) The difference is that (as mentioned before) `/dev/random` uses hardware interruptions to generate the random sequence. If there are no interruptions, `/dev/random` could be exhausted and you might have to wait a little bit until you can get the next random number. `/dev/urandom` uses `/dev/random` internally, but it guarantees that it will always have random numbers ready for you.

If you're using linux, just do `cat /dev/random` on a terminal (and prepare to hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> because it will start output really, really random stuff)

```
borrajax@borrajax:/tmp$ cat /dev/random
_+�_�?zta����K�����q�ߤk��/���qSlV��{�Gzk`���#p$�*C�F"�B9��o~,�QH���ɭ�f�޺�̬po�2o�(=��t�0�p|m�e
���-�5�߁ٵ�ED�l�Qt�/��,uD�w&m���ѩ/��;��5Ce�+�M����
~ �4D��XN��?ס�d��$7Ā�kte▒s��ȿ7_���-     �d|����cY-�j>�
                    �b}#�W<դ���8���{�1»
.       75���c4$3z���/̾�(�(���`���k�fC_^C
```

Python uses the OS random generator or a time as a seed. This means that the only place where I could imagine a potential weakness with Python's `random` module is when it's used:

- In an OS without an actual random number generator, **and**
- In a device where `time.time` is always reporting the same time (has a broken clock, basically)

If you are concerned about the actual randomness of the `random` module, you can either go directly to `os.urandom` or use the random number generator in the [pycrypto](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Random.random-module.html) cryptographic library. Those are probably *more random*. I say *more random* because...

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146062/289011]

<sub>Image inspiration came from this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146062/289011)</sub>

Comment: It's not uniformly better to have true randomness. OP did ask about for cryptography, but even then you should be aware of what you're using the data for (for instance, Salsa will always produce 0 from 0). Seeding a pseudorandom number generator is useful for reproducible but arbitrary data, particularly for repeatable testing or sharing levels in randomly generated games.

Comment: @YannVernier, correct, correct. That's why I added a clarification remarking that sometimes using the same seed is desirable as a feature.