# where does the random.random.__doc__ doc string live?

Tags: python-2.7

Where does the text that is invoked by `print random.random.__doc__` live?

FWIW, I've read the docs page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

and understand the interval notation and help()

but reading through C:\Python27\Lib\random.py

I don't find the doc string: `random() -> x in the interval [0, 1).`

Where is the file this text is printed from?

[BorrajaX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284943/python-where-is-random-random-seeded) made me think it might be in os.py, but I couldn't even find urandom in os.py  and after reading this:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom

I figure that os.py isn't the place to look.

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_randommodule.c#l418

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I know nothing of cpython. Does this file live somewhere in C:\Python27 ?

Comment: I think the structure of that folder should be the same as of the repo, so check C:\Python27\Modules

Comment: win7... no C:\Python27\Modules :\ I've access to a Linux OS and will check there. This link has some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857355/where-are-math-py-and-sys-py

Comment: @jonrsharpe, well, I've looked on an Ubuntu system to no avail in usr/lib/python2.7. Found the 2.7.py scripts but no cpython and no Modules... ?

Comment: Then I guess you only have the compiled code locally, not the source.

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe - this was also helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/library.html#where-is-the-math-py-socket-py-regex-py-etc-source-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per @jonrsharpe: Modules/_randommodule.c
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_randommodule.c#l418

This was also helpful:
https://docs.python.org/2/faq/library.html#where-is-the-math-py-socket-py-regex-py-etc-source-file

on my win7 lappy, putting this in the powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\patrick> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter *.c -Recurse
```

resulted in only *.c files associated with ffmpeg...

Slapping this in the python shell per the docs url:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.builtin_module_names
```

I get this:

('__builtin__', '__main__',  ... '**_random**',...)