# one time pad with pad seeded via 'passphrase'

Tags: python, encryption, random

Looking for a theoretical discussion here.  I personally would (and will continue to) use GPG or just SCP for simply getting a file somewhere where only I can decrypt it or only I can download it. Still a discussion of where the following falls short (and by how much) would help my curiosity.

Suppose I want to encrypt a file locally, put it on the internet, and be able to grab it later.  I want to make sure that only people with a certain password/phrase can decrypt the file ... and I insist on incorporating a one-time-pad.

Assuming it's only used to encrypt a message once, if one were to use a very random passphrase (e.g. Diceware) to seed the pad in a reproducible way, would this be a problem?  In python, I would do something like `random.seed("hurt coaster lemon swab lincoln")` and then generate my pad.  I would use the same seed for encryption and decryption.

There are warnings all over the place about how this Mersenne Twister RNG is not suitable for security/cryptography purposes.  I see that it has a very long period, and IIUC, that `random.seed` allows me to choose 16 bytes worth of different seeds ([Python: where is random.random() seeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284943/python-where-is-random-random-seeded/27286733)).

I've heard that the numbers in an OTP should be "truly random", but even if somebody saw, say, the 1st 100 characters of my pad, how much would that help them in determining what the seed of my RNG was (in hopes of decoding the rest)?  I suppose they could brute force the seed by generating pads from every possible random seed and seeing which ones match my first 100 random letters.  Still, there are quite a few random seeds to try, right?

So, how dangerous is this?  And is there a reasonable way to figure out the seed of a sequence generated by common RNGs by peeking at a little bit of the sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-time pad's key is truly-random data of the same size as the plaintext, by definition.  If you're producing it some other way (e.g. by seeding a PRNG), it isn't a one-time pad, and it doesn't have the one-time pad's unbreakability property.

One-time pads are actually a special type of [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher).  There are other stream ciphers too, and yes, they can be quite secure if used properly.  But stream ciphers can also be completely *insecure* if used *improperly*, and your idea of making up your own cipher based on a non-cryptographic PRNG is improper usage from the start.

One-time pads are used when the key must be *impossible* to brute-force even if the attacker has unlimited computing power.  Based on your description, you're just looking for something that's *infeasible* to brute-force by any realistic attacker, and that's what any other decent cipher will give you.  And unless you're protecting nuclear launch codes or something, that's all you need.

Forget the faux-OTP and Mersenne Twister idea and just use something like [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), with something like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) to derive the key from your passphrase.

---

Regarding your specific question about determining the RNG's sequence:  [Mersenne twister's internal state can be determined by observing 2496 bytes of its output.](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/22/cracking_random_number_generators_part_3.html)  And in a stream cipher, it's easy to determine the keystream given the plaintext and ciphertext.  This means that if an attacker has your ciphertext and can determine the first 2496 bytes of your plaintext, he knows the RNG state and can use it to produce the rest of the keystream and decrypt the whole message.

2496 bytes is not feasible to brute-force, but a sophisticated attacker may be able to significantly narrow down the possibilities using intelligent guessing about the content of your plaintext, such as what you might have written about, or what file formats the data likely to be in and the known structure of those file formats.  This is known as [cribbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack), and can provide enough of a starting point that the remaining brute-force attack becomes feasible.

Even better is if the attacker can trick you into [incorporating some specific content into your plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack).  Then he doesn't even have to guess.

Comment: And even so, as the saying goes "if you're typing the letters AES in your code, you're doing it wrong", just use gpg with symmetric mode